# Algorithm for shortest continuous line to join N points

Tags: algorithms, optimization, euclidean-distance

I have a set of points in a 2D plane. I'm searching for an algorithm that:

- Draws a continuous line passing through all the points starting from a
  random point.
- Optimizes for the minimum total line length in Euclidean distance.
- The line should end at the point it started but not cross any
  other point more than once.

In plain terms, suppose we had a paper with N dots on it. We'd take a pencil starting from a random point and try to go through all the points without lifting the pencil and conclude by reaching the point we started at.

I looked into Euclidian minimum spanning tree, but what I'm looking for is a closed loop and not a graph-tree like line. What I'd like in approximation is a Convex Hull that would go through all the points and not just form the perimeter.

Can someone direct me to the right family of algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out what I'm looking for is the Travelling salesman problem.

Comment: you should accept your answer